# Where to store images in Laravel 4 Views

Tags: php, laravel, image-upload

I am working on a restaurant platform and ask myself where to store profile Images best. Do I create a subfolder in my public/images for every restaurant? Or do I store every image with an id? Or store the path to a DB?

Every restaurant has his own profile image + 3 additional images, let's assume I have 100 restaurants, for my understanding this will create 100 subfolders.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could do any of those things. I wouldn't manually create a subfolder for each one, personally - I'd go with the ID approach, i.e. `public/images/restaurants/1.jpg`.

Comment: Is this static data? Does it come from a form where a user uploads said images? If it's not dynamic (user editable) then why would you involve the database in this? If it's static then the only concern is making sure you can easily identify them later if you need to change them. Regarding identifying them by ID - I'd put all of the media related to one restaurant in a folder that contains the restaurant's ID. That way you can easily swap the entire folder instead of manually swapping individual images.

Comment: @sergio: The image(s) will come from a form. When the user/restraunt creates the account he uploads the image(s), it`s quite possible that he will change his picture from time to time

Comment: Then I'm guessing you'll have to handle _deleting_ a restaurant too, right? Having a single folder is going to be a lot easier. I'd go with a single folder named `restaurant-%id%` and standard names for each image inside ("logo-large.png", "left-banner.png" ...).

Answer (score 1):

Create folder public/assets/images/restaurants

Save the image as restaurantname_imagename

I think this is the best way.